# How do I get Mongoose to find none Mongoose created data within MongoDB?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Can someone please stop me from going insane!

I have a MongoDB database which has a simply database that was created and populated via Mongoose, this works great I can perform finds woth no problems at all.

I went into the Mongo console and created a new database with just use newDB and the performed a simple insert, I inserted several records and they appeared fine within Mongo. I can find on them and so all the Mongo operations but when I try to perform a find on this database Mongoose returns a null???

I have noticed that the database I created in Mongo console does not create the '__v' field which I believe is for Mongoose internal indexing uses, I have created this field in my custom tables but still no joy I just cannot create data from outside of Mongoose and use it within my app??????

I have spent hours looking into this and reading maybe I just missed something but honestly I cannot find a thing on this and many people must hit this every week????

**Sorry here is the code I am running against the database:

```
exports.adduser = function(req, res){
    var mongoose = require("mongoose");
    mongoose.connect("localhost/nm", function(err){
        if(err)throw(err);
        console.log("Connected to MongoDB successfully...")
        var schema = mongoose.Schema({
            Firstname: String,
            Lastname: String,
            MiddleInitial: String,
            Password: String,
            Username: String
        });
        var auser = mongoose.model("Users", schema);
        auser.find({}, function(err, alist){
            console.log(">>>>"+alist);
        });
    });
```

**

Thanks again!!!!! for your input it is very much appreciated....

Comment: You are probably making a simple mistake with your DB connection string or connecting to a different host or something. However, if you have an actual code problem, we can't help you unless you post code snippets.

Comment: Or the collection name that Mongoose uses doesn't match the name of the collection that you stuffed your data into. You can manually set it using [the `collection` option](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#collection).

Comment: The collection name is 'Users' and I presume that the mapper uses the model name to map directly to the table name so hopefully that part is correct...

Comment: @user2855262 a model named `Users` will be stored in a collection named `users` (lowercased). Also, a model named `User` (singular) will  be stored in a collection named `users`, too. So you probably have to be explicit in the collection that should be used.

Comment: Robert! cheers that helped a lot and you where correct! I have can now link and read from any collection thanks! appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

try inspecting mongo instance with

```
show dbs
use <dbName>
```

in mongo shell to make sure you are using the right database and then

```
show collections
```

or alternatively

```
db.getCollectionNames()
```

To see if your collections are there or not.

__v is a document version property incremented only for array operations(mongoose 3).
Your connection string might be wrong.

Comment: I have inspected the collection and all seems perfectly in order, the table is the correct name and the records exist but the find just will not work???? Although it works perfectly find if the table (collection) and data was created within mongoose natively????

Answer (score 0):

Anyone experiencing this problem and I know there are a good few read the comment by robertklep above it solved my problems very quickly!

DOnt know how the accept a comment sorry!